SignalR Core-Send Message to Group Outside of Hub
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with a SignalR endpoint:
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

}).AddJsonProtocol(jsonOptions => { jsonOptions.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; });

app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub", options =>
{
});

I have a Blazor client inside OnInitializedAsync:
HubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("https://localhost:7000/chatHub"), options =>
    {            
        options.Headers.Add("BusinessId", businessId.ToString());

    }).AddJsonProtocol(o =>
    {
        o.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;

    }).WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

HubConnection.On<ChatMessageDTO>("ReceiveMessage", async (msg) =>
{
    Model?.ChatMessages?.Add(msg);
    var messageId = await ChatService.AddNewMessage(msg, Cts.Token);
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
});

await HubConnection.StartAsync(Cts.Token);

Everything is working correctly. I can send and receive messages from my SignalR beacon to my client callbacks. However, If I try to send a group message to a Blazor client callback from outside of the hub, I get inconsistent results if any.
Here's my API service:
public class FcmService : IFcmService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hub { get; }
    
    public FcmService(IHubContext<ChatHub> hub)
    {
       _hub = hub;
    }

    public async Task UpdateUi(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var group = string.Format("{0}{1}", message.BusinessId, "-Dispatchers");

        await _hub.Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}

When I send the message to a group, the Blazor client callback never gets hit. If I change this line:
await _hub.Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);

to:
await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);

it works every time.
How do I send a message to a group from outside of the hub?
UPDATE
Here's how I'm adding groups:
await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);


Please show how you put users in the group

@BrianParker My header parameter is null when using WASM so it was only working with InteractiveServer. Your question made me look in the right place, thanks!

Thanks to Brian Parker, I found my issue. If you're using WASM or InteractiveAuto, make sure to pass in the parameters as a query string and not a header. I did like this:
var url = "";
if (OperatingSystem.IsBrowser())
{
    url = string.Format("https://localhost:7000/chatHub?BusinessId={0}", businessId);
}
else
{
    url = "https://localhost:7000/chatHub";
}

HubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri(url), options =>
    {            
        options.Headers.Add("BusinessId", businessId.ToString());

    }).AddJsonProtocol(o =>
    {
        o.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;

    }).WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

